# Wrap text to next line using Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

[image]I've created a constraint layout

```
 ConstraintLayout(
        Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .wrapContentHeight()
    ) {

        Image(
            painter = rememberImagePainter(it.photoUrl.toString()),
            modifier = Modifier
                .constrainAs(photo) {
                    start.linkTo(parent.start, margin = 30.dp)
                    top.linkTo(parent.top, margin = 30.dp)
                }
                .width(130.dp)
        )

        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .constrainAs(holder) {
                    start.linkTo(photo.end, margin = 30.dp)
                    top.linkTo(photo.top)
                    bottom.linkTo(photo.bottom)
                    end.linkTo(parent.end, margin = 30.dp)
                }
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .wrapContentHeight(),
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
        ) {
            Text(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .wrapContentWidth()
                    .wrapContentHeight(),
                text = "Lorem Ipsu auto text  ator..."
            )
}
```

As you can see long text can not fit in layout. How Can I wrap text to next line? I tried to change wrapContentWidht() to fillMaxParentWidth but id didn't help.

Comment: On, we can't see. You code contains some undefined symbols, like `it` and missing `createRefs`. Update your answer with [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Why don't you use `Row` at the first place? This layout doesn't seems any hard so `ConstraintLayout` most probably is redundant.

Comment: We cant really see how this code looks in the UI. If you could provide that it would be helpful.

Also I am pretty sure its suggested NOT to use constraint layout in Compose and try to use normal Compose layouts. Composable constraint layout is a unique composable on how it behaves.

Comment: Isn't there a `softwrap` parameter to `Text`?

Comment: Have you tried constraining your `holder` top and bottom to `parent` instead of `photo`? And you have a lot of `wrapContentHeight()`, but isn't it a default behaviour for many components? Also, I agree with the comments above – a lot of the code is missing and there is some unnecessary code. Please simplify it for others to be able to help you.

Comment: I've added a photo to my question. I use constraint layout because that view is more complexs and it's not possible to use Row or Column

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use  `width = Dimension.fillToConstraints` to limit the width to the available space.

within the `constrainAs` block

In your example:

```
.constrainAs(holder) {
   start.linkTo(photo.end, margin = 30.dp)
   top.linkTo(photo.top)
   bottom.linkTo(photo.bottom)
   end.linkTo(parent.end, margin = 30.dp)
   width = Dimension.fillToConstraints
}
```